# Accidentally dropped SQL Server database connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I accidentally dropped SQL Server database connection in SQL Server Management Studio. After i dropped the Connection and pushed "OK" the database was put into single user mode and then the database was taken offline and not shown in the object-explorer.

Is there any Point to rettach the database? I dont find any .BAK Datas or the Databasename in the Restore Options.

I tryed already, but get errors

```
USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

I hope there is something i can do. Thx

```
EDIT:
```

[image]

Steps i did right Click on the Database -> Task -> Detach , than i was in the following Windows and clicked on "Drop Conections" and clicked "OK" and than she went into single user mode and went offline. But after a refresh i didnt saw her in my object Explorer. I followed this steps:

[Getting exclusive access to restore SQL Server databases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1407/getting-exclusive-access-to-restore-sql-server-databases/)

so any way to get into single user mode to get her back?

Comment: Dropped the connection?  Sounds like you mean dropped the _database_.  If so, then without backups or a copy of the database somewhere you are basically out of luck.  If what you did was just detach the database (instead of drop) then your database file is probably still available on the server.  You would use that to reattach the database to your server instance.  Can you describe the _exact_ steps that you did to make it disappear from SSMS?

Comment: Agree.  If you dropped the database, and it sounds  like you did, then there is no way that you can return it to multi user mode.  You instead need to restore the database.  After dropping the database the db files should still be in file system.  Where they are depends  on  your configuration.  Search for *.mdf files.

Comment: look at the question i did an Edit. thx

Comment: thx i found the mdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if any *.mdf files exist in file system for the dropped database.  If you find, restore.